# Android app crashes on startup but just after a while of being installed

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

My android app works fine, but when I get home after some hours and I try to run it again, it doesn't work. It crashes after showing the application background for some milliseconds. If I try to debug what is happening, and therefore, connecting the usb and debugger, then it works. It is not waiting for the debugger (at least thereis no message saying that).

Even if I uninstall it and re-install it with the apk it doesn't work, I have to install it with eclipse (run or debug).

I even tried with a release version, with key certificate and everything. But I get the same behavior. In this case looks like reconnecting to debugger doesn't work either.

I target 4.0 and I can't root the device so I can't see the log when it is not connected to the debugger.

It happens in Xiaomi Mi3 and Samsung Galaxy S Duos, the only two devices I can test.

Anyone knows what I could be doing wrong? No background threads are created during this loading, only after and manually by the user. I thought it was because I was calling Log.d() but I commented all these calls and still fails.

Edit: I could recover that from the general Logcat (it does not filter by app name) using the release version that does not work back again when connected to debuger.

```
06-04 21:33:48.254: W/dalvikvm(24046): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41706d58)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046): Process: cs.si.satatt, PID: 24046
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs.si.satatt/cs.si.satatt.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10174 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10174 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getConnectionInfo(IWifiManager.java:768)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getConnectionInfo(WifiManager.java:887)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect$WifiManagerDelegate.getWifiSSID(NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.java:75)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.getCurrentWifiSSID(NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.java:198)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.<init>(NetworkChangeNotifierAutoDetect.java:110)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifier.setAutoDetectConnectivityStateInternal(NetworkChangeNotifier.java:129)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.chromium.net.NetworkChangeNotifier.setAutoDetectConnectivityState(NetworkChangeNotifier.java:116)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkViewDelegate.init(XWalkViewDelegate.java:92)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.init(XWalkView.java:222)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at org.xwalk.core.XWalkView.<init>(XWalkView.java:186)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at cs.si.satatt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:109)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.internal.InstrumentationDelegate.callActivityOnCreate(InstrumentationDelegate.java:76)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
06-04 21:33:48.254: E/AndroidRuntime(24046):    ... 11 more
06-04 21:33:48.254: W/ActivityManager(1109):   Force finishing activity cs.si.satatt/.MainActivity
```

Comment: try to get at least the logcat output (without debugging) and add it to you post.

Comment: What's the status of the app at these times? Is it properly closed or is it only Paused?

Comment: ok just by trying things randomly (things that changed from work to home) I realised that if I disconnect the wifi it works, it is something about the WIFI_STATE permission. But I don't get what is the problem If I am correctly connected to the WIFI

Comment: Just to make sure: do you have `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE based on more information
So based on the additional information, I assume that you have android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your android manifest. If you don't that should solve it.

You should also visit this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
and go through and make sure that you have looked through all of the different required permissions because I am pretty sure that is the problem.

If that doesn't work, upload your code and the Manifest file and I will look through it to see if anything stands out to me.

OLD RESPONSE
I have a feeling that it is a problem with you leaving the debuggable = true or something of that nature. Check the Manifest file for issues with debugging or network issues, as those are the two things that seem to be changing. Obviously I don't have enough information to give a final answer, just speculating.

Comment: No, actually I don't define that. And the message of waiting for debugger does not appear. But thanks

Comment: I thought I had it because I already used the wifi with the app (but Android-pc connection, not with a router). But maybe I commented it at some point. I will look tomorrow my code to see if it is that, if so I will accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I commented it because it was not together with the other network permissions. Thankfuly I managed to extract the logcat because if not it would have been difficult to imagin that was this the error. Thank you, answer accepted.